# Load filtered hierarchy from self-referencing table in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, hierarchy, self-referencing-table

I have a self-referencing entity `Comment` in my project:

```
public class Comment
{
    public Guid CommentId { get; set; }
    
    public string Content { get; set; }
        
    public Guid? ParentCommentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
        
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
await context.Comment
    .Where(c => c.ParentCommentId == null)
    .Include(c => c.Children)
    .ToListAsync();
```

I want to get all root comments (comments that don't have parents) and load the entire hierarchy of comments.

#### Want do I want to see in the result?

I have the following comments in the database:
[image]

To make it more readable, I represent it in hierarchically order (only `Content` property):

- Hello World!

  - Are you a programmer?

    - Sure
    - What?
- I wanna go to Mars too!

  - See you on the Moon :)

When executing the query, shown above, I want to get something like this (in JSON):

```
[
   {
      "commentId":"be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
      "content":"Hello World!",
      "parentCommentId":null,
      "children":[
         {
            "commentId":"59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
            "content":"Are you a programmer?",
            "parentCommentId":"be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
            "children":[
               {
                  "commentId":"0bb77a43-c7bb-482f-9bf8-55c4050974da",
                  "content":"Sure",
                  "parentCommentId":"59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
                  "children":[
                     
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "commentId":"b8d61cfd-d274-4dae-a2be-72e08cfa9066",
                  "content":"What?",
                  "parentCommentId":"59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
                  "children":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "commentId":"cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
      "content":"I wanna go to Mars too!",
      "parentCommentId":null,
      "children":[
         {
            "commentId":"ab6d6b49-d772-48cd-9477-8d40f133c37a",
            "content":"See you on the Moon :)",
            "parentCommentId":"cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
            "children":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

#### But what do I get?

When I execute this query I have the following result:

```
[
   {
      "commentId":"be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
      "content":"Hello World!",
      "postId":"69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
      "post":null,
      "parentCommentId":null,
      "parentComment":null,
      "commentRates":[
         
      ],
      "inverseParentComment":[
         {
            "commentId":"59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
            "content":"Are you a programmer?",
            "postId":"69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
            "post":null,
            "parentCommentId":"be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
            "commentRates":[
               
            ],
            "inverseParentComment":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "commentId":"cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
      "content":"I wanna go to Mars too!",
      "postId":"69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
      "post":null,
      "parentCommentId":null,
      "parentComment":null,
      "commentRates":[
         
      ],
      "inverseParentComment":[
         {
            "commentId":"ab6d6b49-d772-48cd-9477-8d40f133c37a",
            "content":"See you on the Moon :)",
            "postId":"69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
            "post":null,
            "parentCommentId":"cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
            "commentRates":[
               
            ],
            "inverseParentComment":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**So, I get the following hierarchy:**

- Hello World!

  - Are you a programmer?
- I wanna go to Mars too!

  - See you on the Moon :)

**Instead of this:**

- Hello World!

  - Are you a programmer?

    - Sure
    - What?
- I wanna go to Mars too!

  - See you on the Moon :)

Why does it work so? How can I fix this problem?

#### Working, but dirty solution

```
List<Comment> allComments = await context.Comment
    .Include(c => c.Children)
    .ToListAsync();

List<Comment> filteredComments = allComments.Where(c => c.ParentCommentId == null);
```

This works, but it's ugly - we load the full hierarchy of comments from the database into the memory and than filter them. It'll work really slow if the database contains, e.g., 1 million comments.

#### Update

In my case there is no need to use recursive CTE. See update for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67438335/recursive-cte-in-ef-core-automapper-projectto). It looks like the idea introduced by Greg Ogle, but more simplified.

Comment: Recursive CTE is not supported by EF Core. So do that by the SQL, if you really care about performance.

Comment: Take the much more powerful ORM linq2db. You can use [CTE](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html) in it.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, thank you. I think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply load the flat data from the Comment table, it is reasonably fast. To assist in lookups, you can use a `Dictionary<{Guid or whatever type makes sense}, {Comment object type}>`. The lookup on Dictionary uses a HashTable (I'm pretty sure) and is fast. So, once you have your root Comments, the subsequent lookups will be fast.

Here is code for a Console app to demonstrate. It does take a few seconds for it to run. Perhaps further optimization is possible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Timers;

namespace DictionaryHierarchyTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            var commentsFlat = new List<CommentFlat>();
            var parentLookup = new Dictionary<Guid, List<CommentFlat>>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                var id = Guid.NewGuid();
                commentsFlat.Add(new CommentFlat
                {
                    Id = id,
                    ParentId = Guid.Empty,
                    Text = $"Some text for ID:{id}"
                });

                for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    var childId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    commentsFlat.Add(new CommentFlat
                    {
                        Id = childId,
                        ParentId = id,
                        Text = $"Some text for ID:{childId} Parent ID:{id}"
                    });

                    
                    for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                    {
                        var grandChildId = Guid.NewGuid();
                        commentsFlat.Add(new CommentFlat
                        {
                            Id = grandChildId,
                            ParentId = childId,
                            Text = $"Some text for ID:{grandChildId} Parent ID:{childId}"
                        });
                    }

                }
            }

            foreach (var cf in commentsFlat)
            {
                if (!parentLookup.ContainsKey(cf.ParentId))
                {
                    parentLookup.Add(cf.ParentId, new List<CommentFlat>());
                }

                parentLookup[cf.ParentId].Add(cf);
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            var ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine($"There are {commentsFlat.Count} comments");
            Console.WriteLine($"{String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10)} to randomly populated.");
            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();

            var commentHierarchy = new List<Comment>();

            foreach (var cf in commentsFlat)
            {
                if (cf.ParentId == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    var comment = new Comment
                    {
                        Id = cf.Id,
                        ParentId = cf.ParentId,
                        Children = BuildHierarchy(cf.Id, parentLookup),
                        Text = cf.Text
                    };
                    commentHierarchy.Add(comment);
                }
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();
            ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine($"{String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10)} to make hierarchical");
            //foreach (var c in commentHierarchy) {
            //    PrintHiearchy(c, 1);
            //}
        }
        static string Tabs(int n)
        {
            return new String('\t', n);
        }
        private static void PrintHiearchy(Comment comment, int level) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Tabs(level)}{comment.Text}");
            foreach(var child in comment.Children){ PrintHiearchy(child, level + 1); }
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                              e.SignalTime);
        }

        private static List<Comment> BuildHierarchy(Guid parentId, Dictionary<Guid, List<CommentFlat>> flatComments)
        {
            if (flatComments.ContainsKey(parentId))
            {
                return flatComments[parentId].Select(c => new Comment
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    ParentId = c.ParentId,
                    Text = c.Text,
                    Children = BuildHierarchy(c.Id, flatComments)
                }).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<Comment>();
            }
        }

    }

    public class Comment
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public List<Comment> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class CommentFlat
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Your solution is great when we work with little-medium collections. But for big collections of data it's better to use CTEs.