# Recursive CTE in EF Core + Automapper ProjectTo

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, automapper, recursive-cte

**In my project I have types `Comment` and `CommentDto`:**

```
public class Comment
{
    public Guid CommentId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Guid PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentCommentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> InverseParentComment { get; set; }
}
class CommentDto
{
    public Guid CommentId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentCommentId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CommentDto> InverseParentComment { get; set; }
}
```

`Comment` will be mapped into `CommentDto`. Here is the [configuration](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#configuration):

```
cfg.CreateMap<Comment, CommentDto>();
```

**I have the following recursive CTE, encapsulated inside of table-valued Function:**

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_PostCommentHierarchy] (@postId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT CommentId, Content, PostId, ParentCommentId 
        FROM dbo.Comment
        WHERE ParentCommentId IS NULL and PostId = @postId

        UNION ALL

        SELECT child.CommentId, child.Content, child.PostId, child.ParentCommentId
        FROM dbo.Comment child
        INNER JOIN cte parent
        ON parent.CommentId = child.ParentCommentId
        WHERE parent.PostId = @postId
    )

    SELECT * FROM cte
);
```

This function allows to get the hierarchy of comments of the given post (it takes the ID of a post).

**There are comments stored in the database:**
[image]

To make it more readable, I represent it in hierarchically order (only `Content` property):

- Hello World!

  - Are you a programmer?

    - Sure
    - What?
- I wanna go to Mars too!

  - See you on the Moon :)

#### Call function `fn_PostCommentHierarchy` using EF Core

```
List<Comment> commentHierarchy = await _context.Comment
    .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT CommentId, Content, PostId, ParentCommentId FROM dbo.fn_PostCommentHierarchy('post-id-here')")
    .ToListAsync();
```

EF Core sends the following SQL-query to SQL-Server:
`SELECT CommentId, Content, PostId, ParentCommentId FROM dbo.fn_PostCommentHierarchy('post-id-here')`

The code above works as expected (JSON-format was used to increase the readability):

```
[
{
    "commentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
    "content": "Hello World!",
    "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
    "post": null,
    "parentCommentId": null,
    "parentComment": null,
    "commentRates": [],
    "inverseParentComment": [
    {
        "commentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
        "content": "Are you a programmer?",
        "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
        "post": null,
        "parentCommentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
        "commentRates": [],
        "inverseParentComment": [
        {
            "commentId": "0bb77a43-c7bb-482f-9bf8-55c4050974da",
            "content": "Sure",
            "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
            "post": null,
            "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
            "commentRates": [],
            "inverseParentComment": []
        },
        {
            "commentId": "b8d61cfd-d274-4dae-a2be-72e08cfa9066",
            "content": "What?",
            "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
            "post": null,
            "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
            "commentRates": [],
            "inverseParentComment": []
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
},
{
    "commentId": "cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
    "content": "I wanna go to Mars too!",
    "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
    "post": null,
    "parentCommentId": null,
    "parentComment": null,
    "commentRates": [],
    "inverseParentComment": [
    {
        "commentId": "ab6d6b49-d772-48cd-9477-8d40f133c37a",
        "content": "See you on the Moon :)",
        "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
        "post": null,
        "parentCommentId": "cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
        "commentRates": [],
        "inverseParentComment": []
    }
    ]
},
{
    "commentId": "ab6d6b49-d772-48cd-9477-8d40f133c37a",
    "content": "See you on the Moon :)",
    "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
    "post": null,
    "parentCommentId": "cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
    "parentComment": {
        "commentId": "cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
        "content": "I wanna go to Mars too!",
        "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
        "post": null,
        "parentCommentId": null,
        "parentComment": null,
        "commentRates": [],
        "inverseParentComment": []
    },
    "commentRates": [],
    "inverseParentComment": []
},
{
    "commentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
    "content": "Are you a programmer?",
    "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
    "post": null,
    "parentCommentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
    "parentComment": {
        "commentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
        "content": "Hello World!",
        "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
        "post": null,
        "parentCommentId": null,
        "parentComment": null,
        "commentRates": [],
        "inverseParentComment": []
    },
    "commentRates": [],
    "inverseParentComment": [
    {
        "commentId": "0bb77a43-c7bb-482f-9bf8-55c4050974da",
        "content": "Sure",
        "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
        "post": null,
        "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
        "commentRates": [],
        "inverseParentComment": []
    },
    {
        "commentId": "b8d61cfd-d274-4dae-a2be-72e08cfa9066",
        "content": "What?",
        "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
        "post": null,
        "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
        "commentRates": [],
        "inverseParentComment": []
    }
    ]
},
{
    "commentId": "0bb77a43-c7bb-482f-9bf8-55c4050974da",
    "content": "Sure",
    "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
    "post": null,
    "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
    "parentComment": {
        "commentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
        "content": "Are you a programmer?",
        "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
        "post": null,
        "parentCommentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
        "parentComment": {
            "commentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
            "content": "Hello World!",
            "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
            "post": null,
            "parentCommentId": null,
            "parentComment": null,
            "commentRates": [],
            "inverseParentComment": []
        },
        "commentRates": [],
        "inverseParentComment": [
        {
            "commentId": "b8d61cfd-d274-4dae-a2be-72e08cfa9066",
            "content": "What?",
            "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
            "post": null,
            "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
            "commentRates": [],
            "inverseParentComment": []
        }
        ]
    },
    "commentRates": [],
    "inverseParentComment": []
},
{
    "commentId": "b8d61cfd-d274-4dae-a2be-72e08cfa9066",
    "content": "What?",
    "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
    "post": null,
    "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
    "parentComment": {
        "commentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
        "content": "Are you a programmer?",
        "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
        "post": null,
        "parentCommentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
        "parentComment": {
            "commentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
            "content": "Hello World!",
            "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
            "post": null,
            "parentCommentId": null,
            "parentComment": null,
            "commentRates": [],
            "inverseParentComment": []
        },
        "commentRates": [],
        "inverseParentComment": [
        {
            "commentId": "0bb77a43-c7bb-482f-9bf8-55c4050974da",
            "content": "Sure",
            "postId": "69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf",
            "post": null,
            "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
            "commentRates": [],
            "inverseParentComment": []
        }
        ]
    },
    "commentRates": [],
    "inverseParentComment": []
}]
```

**Note**: I made bold comments, that don't have a parent (root comments).

#### Map `Comment` into `CommentDto`

The code above works with entity-type `Comment`, but I want to map it into `CommentDto`. So, let's use `ProjectTo` for this purpose:

```
List<CommentDto> commentHierarchy = await _context.Comment
    .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT CommentId, Content, PostId, ParentCommentId FROM dbo.fn_PostCommentHierarchy('post-id-here')")
    .ProjectTo<CommentDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync();
```

**Note**: `_mapper` is an object of type `IMapper`.

I think, the result should be similar to the result, that I got before using `ProjectTo`. But it looks like:

```
[
{
    "commentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
    "content": "Hello World!",
    "parentCommentId": null,
    "inverseParentComment": [
    {
        "commentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
        "content": "Are you a programmer?",
        "parentCommentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
        "inverseParentComment": null
    }
    ]
},
{
    "commentId": "cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
    "content": "I wanna go to Mars too!",
    "parentCommentId": null,
    "inverseParentComment": [
    {
        "commentId": "ab6d6b49-d772-48cd-9477-8d40f133c37a",
        "content": "See you on the Moon :)",
        "parentCommentId": "cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
        "inverseParentComment": null
    }
    ]
},
{
    "commentId": "0bb77a43-c7bb-482f-9bf8-55c4050974da",
    "content": "Sure",
    "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
    "inverseParentComment": []
},
{
    "commentId": "b8d61cfd-d274-4dae-a2be-72e08cfa9066",
    "content": "What?",
    "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
    "inverseParentComment": []
},
{
    "commentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
    "content": "Are you a programmer?",
    "parentCommentId": "be02742a-9170-4335-afe7-3c7c22684424",
    "inverseParentComment": [
    {
        "commentId": "0bb77a43-c7bb-482f-9bf8-55c4050974da",
        "content": "Sure",
        "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
        "inverseParentComment": null
    },
    {
        "commentId": "b8d61cfd-d274-4dae-a2be-72e08cfa9066",
        "content": "What?",
        "parentCommentId": "59656765-d1ed-4648-8696-7d576ab7419f",
        "inverseParentComment": null
    }
    ]
},
{
    "commentId": "ab6d6b49-d772-48cd-9477-8d40f133c37a",
    "content": "See you on the Moon :)",
    "parentCommentId": "cfe126b3-4601-4432-8c87-445c1362a225",
    "inverseParentComment": []
}
]
```

**Note**: I made bold comments, that don't have a parent (root comments).
Compare the result before using `ProjectTo` and after. Why they are different?

For the code above EF Core sends the following SQL-query to SQL-server:

```
SELECT [c].[CommentId], [c].[Content], [c].[ParentCommentId], [c0].[CommentId], [c0].[Content], [c0].[ParentCommentId]
FROM (
    SELECT CommentId, Content, PostId, ParentCommentId FROM dbo.fn_PostCommentHierarchy('69f3ca3a-66fc-4142-873d-01e950d83adf')
) AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Comment] AS [c0] ON [c].[CommentId] = [c0].[ParentCommentId]
ORDER BY [c].[CommentId], [c0].[CommentId]
```

#### Questions

Why the result before using `ProjectTo` and the result after using `ProjectTo` are not the same?
How to fix this problem?

#### Update 1

According to Svyatoslav Danyliv:

> Recursive CTE returns flat list, then you have to build hierarchy
> again.

But why in this case I should use recursive CTE?
The following solution works in the same way:

```
List<CommentDto> commentFlatList = await _context.Comment
    .Where(c => c.PostId == Guid.Parse("post-id-here"))
    .ProjectTo<CommentDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync();
                
Dictionary<Guid, CommentDto> commentDictionary = commentFlatList
    .ToDictionary(c => c.CommentId);

foreach (var comment in commentFlatList)
{
    if (comment.ParentCommentId == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (commentDictionary.TryGetValue((Guid) comment.ParentCommentId, out CommentDto parent))
    {
        parent.Children.Add(comment);
    }
}

List<CommentDto> commentHierarchy = commentFlatList.Where(c => c.ParentCommentId == null);
```

*Note*: I used `Dictionary` instead of `Lookup` ([see this example](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2738#issuecomment-409990374)), but it doesn't change the idea.

#### Update 2

Let's have a look at the code from the Update 1:

```
List<CommentDto> commentFlatList = await _context.Comment
        .Where(c => c.PostId == Guid.Parse("post-id-here"))
        .ProjectTo<CommentDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .ToListAsync();
```

It will be translated by EF Core into the following:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [c].[CommentId], [c].[Content], [c].[ParentCommentId]
FROM [Comment] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[PostId] = @__request_PostId_0',N'@__request_PostId_0 uniqueidentifier',@__request_PostId_0='post-id-here'
```

Comment: You call recursive CTE to do not load whole table from  database. Only needed leaf.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, why do you think that I load the whole table? I updated my question again to show the SQL-query that EF Core sends to the database

Comment: Yes, if you can filter out by PostId, CTE is not needed.

Comment: Thank you. I'll confirm your answer. It can be used when you must use recursive CTE. But I my case I can simplify the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive CTE returns flat list, then you have to build hierarchy again.

```cs
var commentHierarchy = await _context.Comment
    .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT CommentId, Content, PostId, ParentCommentId FROM dbo.fn_PostCommentHierarchy('post-id-here')")
    .ProjectTo<CommentDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync();

var lookup = commentHierarchy.ToLookup(x => x.commentId);

foreach (var c in commentHierarchy)
{
    if (lookup.Contains(c.commentId))
        c.inverseParentComment.AddRange(lookup.Item[c.commentId]);
}

var result = commentHierarchy.Where(c => c.parentCommentId == null);
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I updated my question, please have a look